# Pattern to validate the email id entered in EditText

Tags: android

Pattern Matching to validate the entered emailid in Edittext.

```
Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9+._%-+]{1,256}" + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}" + "(" + "." + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25}" + ")+");
```

Comment: Pattern
   .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9+._%-+]{1,256}" + "@"
     + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}" + "(" + "."
     + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25}" + ")+");

Comment: Sir this is copy pasted but i am unable to understand it...

Comment: Check this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: any other simple option u have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below method for checking valid email id.

```
/**
 * method is used for checking valid email id format.
 * 
 * @param email
 * @return boolean true for valid false for invalid
 */
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    boolean isValid = false;

    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This : It's Running well for me.

`Set Input Type "Email"` for your Edit Text in XML File.

```
public void Is_Valid_Email()
        {
        if(Email_Text.getText().toString()!=null)
        {
            if(isEmailValid(Email_Text.getText().toString())==false ) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Email Address ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Valid_Email=null;
            }
            else
            {
                Valid_Email=Email_Text.getText().toString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Valid_Email=null;
        }

}// end of email
```

**// Android Provide Default Method To Validate Email Address**

```
boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) 
{
    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
} // end of email matcher
```

Enjoy .

Comment: its better to use default rather than hand made. Great answer...:-)

Answer (score 1):

Use below function for validate email Id.

```
public boolean isValidEmailAddress(String emailAddress)
{  
    String  expression="^[\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";  
    CharSequence inputStr = emailAddress;  
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);  
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);  
    return matcher.matches();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your regular expression with this

> "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\.+[a-z]+"

or follow below link for email pattern in java

[Email pattern in java](http://sourcecodeandroid.blogspot.in/2012/04/email-pattern-validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression for `EMAIL ADDRESS VALIDATION`

```
static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
        "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
  String email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

if(!(_email.matches(EMAIL_PATTERN)))
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: @VarunVishnoi i think you post question for increase your reputation. Why are you ask for vote your question every time ?

Comment: because i need 15 reputation only as minimum... u r right sir... everything is taking time here... i cant chat for my question, i cant post question before 20 minutes. Thats why i m asking to vote me up... but no problem sir i can mange. Thankq

Comment: @VarunVishnoi if you want to increase your reputation then give answer to questions !!  it takes less time to get more reputation .